# Parsing json using jq depending upon the type

Tags: arrays, json, bash, parsing, jq

I want to parse a json depending upon it's type since it varies at times. If the json is a array I need to get the first element or if it's not I need just that element! Below is a simpler version of it which I tried to work on.

```
#!/bin/bash

word='[0,1]'
word=$(echo $word | jq 'if type=="array" then "'$word[0]'" else "'$word'" end')
echo $word
```

It outputs `"[0,1][0]"` where as I expected the passing condition to be assigned to the variable, which is just 0. Because in the below case it just printed "yes".

```
#!/bin/bash

word='[0,1]'
word=$(echo $word | jq 'if type=="array" then "yes" else "no" end')
echo $word
```

Why is there a difference and how to achieve the former?

Comment: You're explicitly surrounding your value with literal double quotes. That means you're *asking* for it to be treated as a string, as opposed to an expression extracting the first element of a list.

Comment: What if the array is empty?

Comment: I've taken care of that in a different way in the main code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.[0]` to return the first array item :

```
echo "$word" | jq 'if type=="array" then .[0] else . end'
```